# proof of Stone–Weierstrass Theorem

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, weierstrass-approximation

I'm doing exercises for analysis and got stuck, here is the whole problem:

(1)suppose  $C_n=\left[\int_{-1}^1\left(1-x^2\right)^n \mathrm{~d} x\right]^{-1}$ ，show that： $C_n<\sqrt{n}$ ；

(2) suppose $f(x)$ is a continuous function on $[0,1]$ , with $f(0)=f(1)=0$. when $x \notin[0,1]$ , define $f(x)=$ 0 . take  $Q_n(x)=C_n\left(1-x^2\right)^n$. show that :
$$
P_n(x)=\int_{-1}^1 f(x+t) Q_n(t) \mathrm{d} t, \quad 0 \leqslant x \leqslant 1
$$
is a polynomial , and
$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} P_n(x)=f(x)
$$

uniformly converges on $[0,1]$ ;

(3) when $f(0)=f(1)=0$ does not occur, proof Stone-Weierstrass THM.

for (1)I've tried induction but when I make it from n
to n+1,I don't know whether can I split up the integration.

and I also can't get the whole view of the proof
. can anyone help? thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: sry for that. I've added the whole problem

Answer (score 1):

The post provides a proof of the Weierstrass theorem. Concerning $C_n$ the integral is used in proving the Wallis formula.
In order to obtain the estimate we make use of the Bernoulli inequality $(1+a)^n\ge  1+na,$ $a>-1,$ and proceed as follows.
$$ \int\limits_{-1}^1(1-x^2)^n\,dx =2 \int\limits_0^1(1-x^2)^n\,dx\ge  2\int\limits_{0}^{n^{-1/2}}(1-x^2)^n\,dx \\
\ge2\int\limits_{0}^{n^{-1/2}}(1-nx^2)\,dx=2[n^{-1/2}- {\textstyle{1\over 3}}n^{-1/2}]=\textstyle{4\over 3}n^{-1/2} $$
Thus $C_n\le {3\over 4}n^{1/2}.$

The formula $(2)$ holds since the mass of $Q_n$ is equal $1$ and it is concentrated near $0$ for large values of $n.$ Namely for any $0<\delta<1$ we have
$$\lim_n\int\limits_{\delta\le |x|\le 1}Q_n(t)\,dt=0$$